# Ionic 2 , Cant find app folder (mac)

Tags: macos, terminal, ionic2

I am tried to install ionic 2 :

```
sudo npm install -g ionic@beta

ionic start mytest --v2 --ts
```

and then i check the ionic version (ionic -v ) its tell me that my
 version is : 1.7.8 
it seems that i have the older version of ionic

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance installed Ionic one, after installing ionic 2? If so run:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic@beta
```

again and everything should start working.